# Can't recognize a word in video

Tags: listening

On the following video - what's the word on **22:15** after "The fifth record - the most beautiful..."? 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0iaG0RN37k (Warning: the video contains language that some may find offensive)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah **[epiphany](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epiphany)** is kind of a hard word to decipher if you don't know it. It is meaning #2. He states the content of the epiphany starting at ~22:25. Notice we use **at** in this context.

Comment: Thing is - I knew this word, but it seemed like it was something else. And thank you for correcting me:)

Just to make sure: "meaning #2" is "a visible manifestation to humankind of God or a god." or this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(feeling)? I still can't understand which one. In my language both make sense.

Comment: In the [dictionary link](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epiphany) in my answer, Meaning #2 is *any moment of great or sudden revelation.*